# Azure Data Factory API Connector

Tags: api, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-api-management, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to access an application via API REST but I am stuck in the process using ADF.
Basically this process consists in 2 steps.
1 - Getting a session (https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/session)
2 - Authenticating ([https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/login?locale=en_GB"](https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/login?locale=en_GB%22)) using Username and Password.

I have created a Linked Service (Rest) and set the Base URL as (https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/session)
Authentication Anonymous.

Then I create a Data Set to point this API and finally I create a "Copy Data" and tried to set on the Additional Header the authentication's details, but it is not working, I got an error 405.

Basically I can run the below script using Powershell and it is working as expected, but is required to use it on ADF instead.

The script in Powershell is this one.

```
$user = "xxxxxx@mail.com"
$pass = "123456789"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$pass)))

#Get Session
$url = "https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/session"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method Post -SessionVariable se

#Authentication
Write-Host "Authenticating" -ForegroundColor Green
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
}
$headers
$url = "https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/login?locale=en_GB"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get -WebSession $se

#List Reports
$url = "https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/report"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $url -Method Get -WebSession $se
$response
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the 3 steps are separate, and only the last one fetches data, you should break up the process into multiple activities.

Use Web Activity for the first two steps,

- https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/session
- [https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/login?locale=en_GB"](https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/login?locale=en_GB%22)

extract the session variable or Authentication from the web activities.  Pass it to the copy activity. The copy activity should target

- https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/report

Comment: Thank you MartinJaffer-MSFT!

Its worked as a charm!.

Now I can execute the steps 1 and 2. 
Regarding the step 3 if I use a Copy activity what I can put on "Source Dataset"? As I am not using any linked Service.

I have created a third step using the Web activity and now can see the data from the report on the debug log.

But I need to use the Copy activity to save this report data (or the resulting log data from the previous Web activity) into a SQL Server table somehow.

Regards,

Comment: While web activity can be used to retrieve data, there is a payload limit.  Web activity is different from copy activity, in that the response is made available to the pipeline, rather than written to a sink.
The stored procedure activity can be abused  and made into a write mechanism.  Lookup activity can also be abused via the "query" option, as long as some data is returned in the end (insert statement + select statement).

Comment: I would recommend you use either a REST or HTTP linked service & dataset for step 3 source.  If your api does pagination, and returns JSON form, REST connector is useful.  If there is no pagination or data is returned in any other format, HTTP connector should be used.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your explanation.
I have tried to use REST API and test it using different parameters, and configurations but unsuccessfully.

Basically on the Linked Service I set the Base URL (https://horizon.akixi.com/CCS/API/v1/report) and Authentication's type is Anonymous.

Comment: On the "Copy Data Activity" 

1 - I am using this Rest linked service created on step before with Request method GET.

2 - I created 2 additional Headers  "Authorization"(Basic Type User and Pass)  and "Cookie" (Session)

I am getting an error "The resource you attempted to access requires you to be logged in with a valid user. Either you have not logged in yet.... "

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems that when I use the "Copy Activity" the GET will execute the "/report" without "/login".
It is like the process is ignoring the step before "Login".

I resume, I think the "Copy Activity" should have to requests 1 - Execute the endpoint "/Login" and then "/Report" endpoint. I think both must exist in the same Copy activity (not sure if it is possible).

In fact, the endpoint "/login" does not return anything.

Comment: That is true.  The login must be done in a separate step, as it is a different endpoint.
Use web activity to do the login.  Pass any tokens obtained from login to the Copy Activity.